# Database Design for FAQ app

Tags: mysql, database

I have a current mySQL database, but I don't think it is designed as well as it could be - i'm foreseeing issues when it comes to creating queries within my application.

Can anyone help me with designing a database for the following scenario -

I have a set of questions each with a title, an answer, and some tags.  These questions are assigned to categories.  Users logged on to the system can change any attribute of the question.  The change must be approved before it shows live on the system.  There must be a way of auditing such that each newly create question or each question that is edited has the details of who edited stored.

The application will provide reports including a list of all changes carried out to a question.

Any help on this would be appreciated.  I can also provide what I have in place already but i think it has some fundamental issues.

Comment: Dave, we can only really answer you if you list what you already have.